# Android - Make a phone call

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to make a phone call with Android using Titanium Appcelerator and i am wondering how to do it

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
      action: Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
      data: '9999999' // number to dial
 });
```

But of course there is something else i need to do.
Thanks in advance

SDK 5.2.2
Appcelerator 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
function call(number){
    number = number.trim();
        var call = 'tel:' + number;
        if (OS_IOS) {
            Titanium.Platform.openURL(call);
        } else {

            var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                action : Ti.Android.ACTION_CALL,
                data : call
            });
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
        }

}
```

and add in your manifest in tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <manifest>
            ...
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
            ...
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is android code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```

UPD: As @Masum mentioned, you also need to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thanks @Oleg, but i think your solution is for native development and i need it for Appcelerator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Appcelerator approach:

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:1234567890');
```

If this works for you, mark it as an answer for others.

Comment: Thanks @Soumya, but that code only open the dial pad. I need the phone call.

Comment: So you want it to dial the number instead of opening the dealer and showing the number?

Comment: yes...I need the CALL, Jagu solve my question. Thanks anyway.